# Where is Bitlocker encryption key stored in USB?

Tags: encryption, disk-encryption, bitlocker

I have a USB that contains the Bitlocker key. When I open USB I dont see any files inside. How can I move the Bitlocker key to another USB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked hidden files?

"The key will be saved to the USB drive as a hidden file with the .bek file extension. You can see it if you show hidden files."

Source -- https://www.howtogeek.com/262744/HOW-TO-USE-A-USB-KEY-TO-UNLOCK-A-BITLOCKER-ENCRYPTED-PC/

(Doesn't look like this is a duplicate)

Comment: Thanks. It wasn't a normal hidden file. It was a protected operating system file.